# Как по нажатию на каталог вывести список файлов и папок, а также перемещаться между ними на одной странице?

Tags: php

Всем привет, второй день не могу понять, как по нажатию на вложенную папку вывести её содержимое с использованием одной и той же страницы. Вот выведенные файлы:

[image: Выведенные файлы]

Мне нужно, чтобы выводилось, к примеру, содержимое папки "folder2" в виде списка, как на 1 скриншоте, а в итоге получается вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
<?php
                $folder = 'AYP';
                if(is_dir($folder)) {
                    if($dh = opendir($folder)) {
                        while(($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
                            if($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                                if(is_dir($folder. '/' .$file)){
                                    echo '
                                        <div class="files">
                                            <a href="/'.$folder.'/'.$file.'">
                                                <div class="img-files">
                                                    <img class="imgF" width="24px" src="../uploads/folder.png">
                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                    <a class="file-link" href="/'.$folder.'/'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    ';
                                } else {
                                    echo '
                                        <div class="files">
                                            <a href="/'.$folder.'/'.$file.'">
                                                <div class="img-files">
                                                    <img class="imgF" width="24px" src="../uploads/file.png">
                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                    <a class="file-link" href="/'.$folder.'/'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    ';
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        closedir($dh);
                    }
                }
            ?>
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: второй скриншот - стандартный вовд Апача, если включена опция показа каталогов. Это означает, что ваш скрипт не вызывается Апачем. Причин может быть много, в зависимости от того, как в целом работает ваш сайт